# java.util.Date toString method returns a String with wrong year: 3920 instead of 2020

Tags: java

I have this code:

```
Date date = new Date(2020, 11, 1);

System.out.println(date); // Wed Dec 01 00:00:00 XXX 3920
System.out.println(date.getYear()); // 2020
System.out.println(date.getMonth()); // 11
System.out.println(date.getDay()); // 3
```

As can be seen, it prints year `3920` instead of `2020`. Why does it happen? Any way to fix it without radically changing the code?

PS I know the constructor and the getter methods are deprecated. Unless that is the reason for the wrong output, I'd prefer to keep using them in this particular example.

Comment: So, from the `Date` constructor, it's doing `int y = year + 1900;`, so you "should" be doing `new Date(120, 11, 1);`, but then this leads to `getYear` returning `120` - so, which "problem" to you want to live with?

Comment: I would strongly suggest moving away from `java.util.Date` and use the newer `java.time` API. @MadProgrammer already provided the reason for this.

Comment: Yeah, don't use those methods.  They're deprecated for a reason.  If you look at the Javadocs, the constructor automatically adds 1900 to the year, so that you can use it for two-digit years.  And the `getYear` automatically subtracts 1900, so that it returns a two-digit year.  In other words, Java, although invented in the 1990s, came with its very own Y2K issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.of( 2020, Month.DECEMBER, 1 )
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using a terrible date-time class, `Date`, which has many tragic design flaws. One of those flaws is an offset of 1900 years.

The solution is simple: Stop using that class. It is now legacy, supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310.

Plus, the `java.util.Date` class does  not fit your need. That class represents a moment, a date with time of day as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours minutes seconds. But you want a date-only, without time of day, without the context of an offset or time zone.

The other `Date`,`java.sql.Date` class, pretends to fit your need as a date-only value. But actually that class inherited from `java.util.Date` in an extremely poor design choice.

## Use `LocalDate`

Instead, use [`java.time.LocalDate`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/LocalDate.html).

This class uses **sane numbering**:

- The year 2020 is 2020.
- The months January through December are 1 to 12.

Instantiate via `static` factory methods.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020, 12, 1 ) ;
```

Or use the `Month` enum.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2020, Month.DECEMBER, 1 ) ;
```

Interrogate for parts.

```
int y = ld.getYear() ;
int m = ld.getMonthValue() ;
String month = ld.etMonth().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ) ;
int d = ld.getDayOfMonth() ;
String dow = ld.getDayOfWeek().getDisplayName( TextStyle.FULL , Locale.JAPAN ) ;
```